# Using jQuery to find visible items

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have this code that shows a video player and that video's information and hides it when the back button is clicked. However, when I view another video, the back button does not pick up which div is visible the second time around. Does the `:visible` selector have to be linked to `.live()` in order for it to determine which div is visible? If not, why can't it find my visible div?

```
jQuery('ul.projects li').click(function() {

var videolist = jQuery(this).closest('ul');
var videoplayer = jQuery(videolist).prev();
var videoplayerID = jQuery(videoplayer).find("div:first").attr("id");
var filename = jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt");

var infoclass = '.' + filename.replace(/ /g,'');

  jwplayer(videoplayerID).setup({
    'flashplayer': '/_/jw/player.swf',
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '258',
    'height': '145',
    'file': '/_/videos/' + filename + '.mp4',
    'autostart': true,
    'events': {
        onComplete: function(event) {
            jQuery(videoplayer).fadeOut(function() {
                jQuery(infoclass).fadeOut();
                jwplayer(videoplayerID).remove();
                jQuery(videolist).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    }
  });

  jQuery(videolist).fadeOut(function() {
    jQuery(videoplayer).fadeIn();
    jQuery(infoclass).fadeIn();
  });

});

jQuery('.back-to-projects').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var videoplayer = jQuery(this).parent();
    var videolist = jQuery(videoplayer).next();
    var videoplayerID = jQuery(videoplayer).find("div:first").attr("id");
    var videoinfo = '.' + jQuery(this).siblings("div:visible").not("#video-player-1_wrapper, #video-player-2_wrapper").attr("class");
    alert(videoinfo);
    jQuery(videoinfo).fadeOut();
    jQuery(videoplayer).fadeOut(function() {
        jwplayer(videoplayerID).remove();
        jQuery(videolist).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

and the html

```
<div class="video-container" style="display:none;">
    <div id="video-player-1_wrapper" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div class="DwightHoward" style="display:none;"><p>Dwight Howard, son.</p></div>
    <div class="BrianDeegan" style="display:none;"><p>Brian Deegan, son.</p></div>
    <div class="PatrickWillis" style="display:none;"><p>Patrick Willis, son.</p></div>
    <div class="Castles" style="display:none;"><p>Castles, son.</p></div>
    <div class="Springtime" style="display:none;"><p>Springtime, son.</p></div>
    <div class="Powerbar" style="display:none;"><p>Powerbar, son.</p></div>

    <a class="back-to-projects" href="" title="Back">Back</a>
</div>


<ul class="projects">
    <li><img class="t" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/dwight-howard.jpg" alt="Dwight Howard" /></li>
    <li><img class="t" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/brian-deegan.jpg" alt="Brian Deegan" /></li>
    <li><img class="t" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/patrick-willis.jpg" alt="Patrick Willis" /></li>
    <li><img class="b" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/castles.jpg" alt="Castles" /></li>
    <li><img class="b" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/springtime.jpg" alt="Springtime" /></li>
    <li><img class="b" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/powerbar.jpg" alt="Powerbar" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up simplifying the process by add a class `.visible` to the visible element, and then removing it when I wanted to hide it. So shoot me.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some more HTML or JS missing, your code is quite complicated for what it needs to do. Here's a solution that involves a lot less JS (and better practices, see below), and only 1 extra HTML element (which creates better logical separation anyway).

```
  var $videolist = jQuery('ul.projects');
  var $videoplayer = jQuery('.video-container');
  var videoplayerID = jQuery('#video-player-1_wrapper').attr('id');

  jQuery('ul.projects li').click(function() {
    var filename = jQuery(this).find("img").attr("alt");
    var $infoclass = jQuery('.' + filename.replace(/ /g,''));

    jwplayer(videoplayerID).setup({
      'flashplayer': '/_/jw/player.swf',
      'id': 'playerID',
      'width': '258',
      'height': '145',
      'file': '/_/videos/' + filename + '.mp4',
      'autostart': true,
      'events': {
          onComplete: function(event) {
              $videoplayer.fadeOut(function() {
                  $infoclass.fadeOut();
                  jwplayer(videoplayerID).remove();
                  $videolist.fadeIn();
              });
          }
      }
    });

    $videolist.fadeOut(function() {
      $videoplayer.fadeIn();
      $infoclass.fadeIn();
    });

  });

  jQuery('.back-to-projects').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('.info div:visible').fadeOut();
      $videoplayer.fadeOut(function() {
          jwplayer(videoplayerID).remove();
          $videolist.fadeIn();
      });
  });

<div class="video-container" style="display:none;">
    <div id="video-player-1_wrapper" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="DwightHoward" style="display:none;"><p>Dwight Howard, son.</p></div>
      <div class="BrianDeegan" style="display:none;"><p>Brian Deegan, son.</p></div>
      <div class="PatrickWillis" style="display:none;"><p>Patrick Willis, son.</p></div>
      <div class="Castles" style="display:none;"><p>Castles, son.</p></div>
      <div class="Springtime" style="display:none;"><p>Springtime, son.</p></div>
      <div class="Powerbar" style="display:none;"><p>Powerbar, son.</p></div>
    </div>

    <a class="back-to-projects" href="" title="Back">Back</a>
</div>


<ul class="projects">
    <li><img class="t" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/dwight-howard.jpg" alt="Dwight Howard" /></li>
    <li><img class="t" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/brian-deegan.jpg" alt="Brian Deegan" /></li>
    <li><img class="t" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/patrick-willis.jpg" alt="Patrick Willis" /></li>
    <li><img class="b" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/castles.jpg" alt="Castles" /></li>
    <li><img class="b" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/springtime.jpg" alt="Springtime" /></li>
    <li><img class="b" src="/_/img/elevator-pitch/thumbs/video/powerbar.jpg" alt="Powerbar" /></li>
</ul>
```

A few points:

You were doing a lot of DOM traversal that wasn't necessary when you could have just directly used selectors by ID/class which is what I did above.

You were also duplicating some vars instead of declaring them above the click events.

The other big issue with your code was doubling up on jQuery objects.

Example:

```
var videolist = jQuery(this).closest('ul');
var videoplayer = jQuery(videolist).prev();
```

The first line returns a jQuery object (videolist). There's no reason to wrap that in jQuery() on the next line. You can safely do:

```
var videolist = jQuery(this).closest('ul');
var videoplayer = videolist.prev();
```

If you look at my code, I use $var to reference a jQuery object. It's purely a personal/style decision, but it helps to quickly tell whether a variable is a jQuery object or not.

Read here for more info about the jQuery object type: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

Comment: I appreciate the response - there is definitely a whole lot more html that isn't shown here (using multiple ul.projects, .video-containers etc) and variables that are defined based on where the click occurs, but your point about consolidating jQuery objects is well taken. I'll definitely be implementing that into my practice. Thanks!

Comment: I hoped that was the case from your code :) Glad you found the solution anyway.